# Update util-linux on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 2.23

Tags: ubuntu

Does anyone know how to update `util-linux` on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` to `util-linux 2.23` version? I really need the `nsenter` command feature which is not present in `util-linux 2.20` I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

You currently can't do that using the standard apt-get approach, because the package is not available in the official repo.

You have a few options:

- install from 3rd party ppa or site that offers binary packages for your distro
- download and compile from source - https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/

Comment: I have tried to install it from an `.rpm` package by converting it do `.deb` with `alien` and an error is raised, couldn't get to install it.

Comment: what's the error? you can always try on a test environment to build the package from source, but that can easily get out of hand, depending on the links with other libraries...

Comment: `dpkg -i util-linux_2.23.2-7.1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 65363 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace util-linux 2.20.1-1ubuntu3 (using util-linux_2.23.2-7.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement util-linux ...
dpkg: error processing util-linux_2.23.2-7.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/bin/login', which is also in package login 1:4.1.4.2+svn3283-3ubuntu5.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux_2.23.2-7.1_amd64.deb`